# Newbie: writing a script for google sheets that will run on all sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-apps-script-editor

I am a real novice at this (not even). Have never written code in my life-just copied the following code off a website that explained how to do it. I a google doc that I need to be sorted according to Column C continuously as new data is added. This is the code I was given:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 2, sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort({column: 3, ascending: true});
}
```

It works partially, but I need it to be applied to all sheets/tabs in the document. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. I cannot understand about `I a google doc that I need to be sorted according to Column C continuously as new data is added.`. Can you explain about the detail of your goal? 2. Can you explain about your current issue? In your script, when a cell or several cells are edited, the script is run for the active sheet. From this situation, I couldn't understand about your current issue for `I need it to be applied to all sheets/tabs in the document.`.

Comment: I don't know code, so I need help changing the script. What I want it to do is that every single time a new row is inserted, the data will be resorted. The document is a list of people, and Column C is the ages. I want to it to stay sorted by age even when new names are added at the bottom of the sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal and your current issue for `I need it to be applied to all sheets/tabs in the document.`. By the way, `new data is added` in your question is the same with `a new row is inserted` in your replying?

Comment: Is the new row being inserted by a human or by some script / import function?

Comment: Human manually adding new info on a new row.

Comment: Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your code includes the line `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` and the rest of you code is based on `sheet`  - so it run only on one sheet, the one that is active when new data is inserted, so the one in which the edit is performed
- If instead you want to perform the sorting on each edit in all sheets of the spreadsheet, you need the method [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) to retrieve all sheets of the spreadsheet as an [array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)
- Subsequently you need to [loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) through the array to apply the sorting function to each sheet

**Sample:**

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var range = sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 2, sheet.getLastColumn());
    range.sort({column: 3, ascending: true});
  }
}
```

**Important:**

The `onEdit` trigger only detects human-made edits like typing of text. If instead you want to fire the trigger on changing the document structure, such as e.g. inserting a new empty row (which is different from typing values into cells of an alreday existing empty row), you would need to replace the `onEdit` trigger, through the [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onChange` trigger, see also [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/diference-between-onedit-or-onchange-trigger)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! This did the trick for me! Saved the day!

Comment: Would you be able to do me a favour and edit the range so that the range that is sorted does not include the first 2 rows? (From Row 3 and on should be sorted)? Thanks!

Comment: The code as it is already starts at row 3, since the start row in [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) is set to 3.